# npm issues laravel popper install

Tags: php, laravel, npm, popper.js

```
npm WARN bootstrap@4.6.0 requires a peer of popper.js@^1.16.1 but none is installed.
```

How to fix this in laravel install? Is there a way around or is this permanent issue?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you using **composer create-project** or **laravel new** command?

Which version of **node** and **npm** you have installed?

Do you have **nvm** installed?

Comment: composer create project

Comment: $ node --version
v13.14.0

Comment: $ npm --version
6.14.4

Comment: Window 7 → I have window 7. I think Nodes latest version doesnt get installed on window 7?

Comment: No NVM installed.

Comment: Using nvm, i changed node version to 13.14, and created a fresh project using composer create, and not able to reproduce this issue not even with `npm install` or `npm run dev`

Comment: Try installing this package: `npm install popper.js --save`

But i can see on the website that this one is deprecated, even though try and see if the "error goes away".

Comment: So I should Try NVM?

Comment: Can NVM be installed through git bash?

Comment: Not sure if changing the node version would solve your problem.
And yes it can be installed from bash

https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#installing-and-updating